# iOS pjsip video: get correct orientation

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, pjsip

using pjsip 2.3.0 I am able to start video call. the only issue is the video orientation. the app supports all orientation on the ipad and portrait only on iphone. after rotating the ipad during video call, the iphone has video view which is not correctly oriented. I know that there is `PJMEDIA_VID_DEV_CAP_ORIENTATION = 128` is defined but i don't know when and how to trigger this method so that video from A to B has the correct orientation. can someone please explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out how to change the orientation in iOS_dev.m in pjmedia.

```
static pj_status_t ios_stream_set_cap(pjmedia_vid_dev_stream *s,
                  pjmedia_vid_dev_cap cap,
                  const void *pval)
{
     struct ios_stream *strm = (struct ios_stream*)s;
     [strm->video_output connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
     capConnection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortraitUpsideDown;
}
```